# mysql query fetching duplicate rows twice using php

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT bp.postID, bp.postTitle, bp.postSlug, bp.authorName,bp.coverPic, bp.postDesc, bp.postDate FROM blog_posts bp INNER JOIN blog_post_cats bpc ON bp.postID=bpc.postID INNER JOIN blog_cats bc ON bpc.catID=bc.catID WHERE bp.STATUS=1 AND catSlug="World-In-360" ORDER BY postID DESC
```

This query is fetching each row twice. Any help with this ?

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to add GROUP BY

```
SELECT bp.postID, bp.postTitle, bp.postSlug, bp.authorName,bp.coverPic, bp.postDesc, bp.postDate 
    FROM blog_posts bp 
INNER JOIN blog_post_cats bpc 
    ON bp.postID=bpc.postID 
INNER JOIN blog_cats bc 
    ON bpc.catID=bc.catID 
WHERE bp.STATUS=1 AND catSlug="World-In-360" 
GROUP BY postID
ORDER BY postID DESC
```

Comment: A good rule-of-thumb is; in the absence of any aggregating functions, NEVER use a GROUP BY clause

Comment: @Strawberry, wat???)))) rule of thumb maybe to use aggregator for each selected column, but not to use - extreme )